# File launches in Launchctl with PID - Status 1

Tags: launchd, python, hosts

I have a Python program that writes to the /etc/hosts file. It works correctly manually entered using the sudo command. I want it to open automatically. I can load it into sudo launchctl but it returns PID - Status 1.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add a link to the python app/script/py file!

Answer (score 3):

PID - Status 1 means that the process doesn't have enough privileges to access some files (presumably /etc/hosts). To be able to execute script as root, you need to move the loader to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

(processes in `/Library/LaunchAgents/` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` are run as current user so they don't have root rights).